# Conditionally Rendering EJS Template Views to the Same Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, ejs

So, very newbie question, but I searched for a couple hours and couldn't find this specific problem (I know I'm doing something dumb).

I am grabbing data from a simple sqlite database table, processing if certain rows are a specific value, pushing them into a table (which I use to push to one of the EJS pages), and then want to render a page based on if there is any data in the table or not.

I want to read the table at a certain interval (using setInterval) and then if there has been a change, update the "view".

All of it has gone decently well, except for when the EJS page actually has to switch from one page to another. I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this, once it's rendered. But, I'd prefer to just render a different page on the same path ('/') that changes on browser refresh.

The initial conditional statement renders the correct EJS page, but like I said, once it needs to switch, the page remains on browser refresh.

I've tried moving the placement of the conditional in multiple places (inside the "get", outside, etc.).

Also tried doing the "if" statement inside a single EJS page, but it just won't refresh once the initial page is rendered and then the function is called again with the setInterval.

```js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
fs = require('fs')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

function query(){
  var db = new sqlite3.Database('./my_database.sqlite', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the chinook database.');
  });

  var sql = `SELECT column1 column1
              FROM myTable
             WHERE column1 = ?`;

  var mkts = []
  db.each(sql, ['a'], (err, row) => {
   if (err) {
     throw err;
   }
   mkts.push(row.column1);
   console.log(mkts);
  });




  db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Close the database connection.');
    console.log(mkts.length);
    if(mkts.length>0){
      console.log(true);
      app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('alert', {mkts:mkts});
      });
    }else{
      console.log(false);
      app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index', {mkts:mkts});
      });
    }

  });
};
query();
setInterval(() => query(), 10000);

app.listen(3000);
```

So basically after opening and then querying the data I want, I'm running the get and render at the db.close. In this code, I can get the "true" and "false" to log appropriately when the DB changes, but the render will not change once the overarching function is run once.

Sorry if its hard to read, but it's been driving me nuts all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic (retrieving the datas, view switch) has to be INSIDE your app.get("/"...
Here, you're querying the datas only once (on server) startup and set a static route with static datas.

Try something like this :

```
// connect to db on startup
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./my_database.sqlite', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the chinook database.');
  });

// define your routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){

      // when route is asked by your browser retrieve the datas
      var sql = `SELECT column1 column1
              FROM myTable
             WHERE column1 = ?`;

      var mkts = []
      db.each(sql, ['a'], (err, row) => {
       if (err) {
          throw err;
       }
        mkts.push(row.column1);
        console.log(mkts);
      });

     // render the good view according to your datas
     if(mkts.length>0){
          res.render('alert', {mkts:mkts});
     }
     else {
          res.render('index', {mkts:mkts});
     }

});

app.listen(3000);
```

In addition, your setInterval to refresh the view cannot be done here, the "refresh" has to be asked by the client. In your view simply put something like this in javacript :

```
  <script>setTimeout(function(){document.location.reload();}, 1000);</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot. I think I had a fundamental misunderstanding about what "app.get()" was doing. After taking your suggestion and using some trial and error, I think I have it figured out!.